# Add file section Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want to add File section like the photo that contain some files of my product on Wordpress
[pic discreption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZJXC.png)

how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'custom_product_tabs' );
function custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['attrib_desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'File', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 100,
        'callback'  => 'attrib_desc_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}

function attrib_desc_tab_content() {
  ?>
  <img src="aaa.jpg">
  <?php
}
```

Comment: where can i put this code !